# Scrapy stops early, no errors

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy, web-crawler

so I am trying to scrape a blog with around 2000 pages of posts but scrapy seems to be finishing early and not getting to the last page.

```
import scrapy


class postsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts"

    # URL's to scrape.
    start_urls = [
        "Removed for privacy"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Calls postDetails Parser.
        post_urls = response.css(
            "div.article-inner > header > h2 > a::attr(href)").extract()
        for url in post_urls:
            post_urls = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=post_urls, callback=self.parsePostDetails)

        # Handles next pages.
        next_page = response.css(
            "#main > nav > div > a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    # Parses each post for its title, postBody, and postDate.
    def parsePostDetails(self, response):
        postString = response.css(
            "div.article-inner > div.entry-content > p::text").extract()
        postTitle = response.css(
            "div.article-inner > header > h1::text").extract()
        postAuth = response.css(
            """div.article-inner > header > div.entry-meta.aftertitle-meta > span.author.vcard
> a > em::text""").extract()
        postTime = response.css(
            "div.article-inner > header > div.entry-meta.aftertitle-meta > span.onDate.date > time.published::text").extract()
        yield {
            'postTitle': str(postTitle),
            'postBody': str(postString),
            'postAuthor': str(postAuth),
            'postDate': str(postTime)
        }
```

```
2019-01-08 14:04:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-01-08 14:04:53 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (600 items) in: posts5.json
2019-01-08 14:04:53 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 242774,
 'downloader/request_count': 641,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 641,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 58016154,
 'downloader/response_count': 641,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 641,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8, 19, 4, 53, 583047),
 'item_scraped_count': 600,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1242,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 40,
 'response_received_count': 641,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 640,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 640,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 640,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 640,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8, 19, 2, 51, 782255)}
2019-01-08 14:04:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I am not too sure what would be causing this. It seems to stop at random points. Any idea why this is happening? I assume it has something to do with the pagination, but I can't figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your spider just fails to find next page:

```
# Handles next pages.
next_page = response.css(
    "#main &gt; nav &gt; div &gt; a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)").extract_first()
if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

try adding:

```
else:
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

This will open up scrapy debug shell and you can interact with objects real time:

```
# open webpage in browser
>>> view(response)
```

Seems like your css for next page might be a bit over-engineered here and some html inconsistency might break it. Try just `a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)`